# How to modify the fields for the RSS feed for a Joomla 2.5 site?

Tags: php, rss, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and have an RSS feed. I need to be able to make a change to the output of the RSS feed, but having difficulty figuring out where this PHP code is to make the change. Or if there is some module to alter this from the backend that I have not yet been able to identify. The URL for it looks like this:

```
http://example.com/stuff/news?format=feed&type=rss
```

The RSS output has fields in it that I need to alter or remove look like this:

```
</description>
            <author>superuser@example.com (Super User)</author>
            <category>News</category>
            <pubDate>Thu, 06 Feb 2014 21:44:43 -0500</pubDate>
        </item>
```

I want to either remove the  field or be able to change what's there so it doesn't say Super User. All the Articles for the RSS news feed are owned by the company site there is no reason to have an author field like this so if it won't break anything else in the RSS feed format I'd like to know if it's OK to remove it. I have looked at other RSS feeds from non-Joomla websites and noticed there isn't even an Author field there so I'm assuming it can be removed. But the question still remains for me where to remove this or even change it.

The RSS feed is set-up through the Syndication Feeds module, but I looked in the PHP code there and can't find anything that relates to the fields used in the RSS feed directly.

In the above URL I see it's using the module mod_articles_news, if I'm correct. I looked in there too but nothing that points to what I'm looking for.

I'm not an RSS feed expert so I could simply be looking in the wrong direction to find what I'm looking for. Where is the code for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you are looking for is JOOMLA/components/com_content/views/category/view.feed.php

You will need to create an override so that your changes aren't lost when you update Joomla. To do this, place a copy of view.feed.php here JOOMLA/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/code/com_content/views/category/view.feed.php them make your edits to that file.

Comment: Thanks, Brent! After line 54 I added $author = "";, and after line 71 I added $item->authorEmail = "";, and this removed the <author> line completely from the RSS feed.

Comment: @BrentFriar: templatename/code/ ? I never heard of this before. I also searched on google for a documentation on this, but all i found was tempaltename/html and templatename/layout as overwrite-folders.

Comment: You can override anything in the MVC structure - https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core. It does take a plugin to make it work, but no having to hack the core.